# Reduce lists by summing element-wise in purrr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to use `purrr` to sum list elements with the same index. This can be achieved in base R using the following:

```
xx <- list(a = c(1,2,3,4,5), b = c(1,2,3,4,5))
Reduce("+", xx)
```

which provides:

```
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Great! That's what I need, but I want to do it all in `purrr`. `%>% reduce(sum)` gives a single value back. Does anyone know the syntax to do this in `purrr`?

Edit- I forgot to specify, this needs to work for n lists.

Dan

Comment: `%>%` is not a base R operator. It is part of the `magrittr` package. Base R would be `Reduce("+", xx)` or `do.call("+", xx)`.

Comment: Not a useful comment, but I've edited my question nonetheless.

Comment: It's not my intention to troll, but note that the initial statement in the R tag says "R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, and graphics. Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do (s. `?reduce`):

```
   xx %>% reduce(`+`)
   [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Comment: That is beautiful, beetroot... I am wondering, why that works, but  `xx %>% reduce(sum)` doesn't? This second option will sum all values into a single one, not by position...

Comment: @JavierFajardo as `sum` first sums up the values of each of the two lists there are only two values left to `reduce` (15 + 15 = 30).